# How do you prevent default events in Angular-Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In the following code sample is there a '*Angular way*' of preventing the default event of a button click or form submit. Currently I'm using 'onsubmit' to accomplish the task.

```dart
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input ng-model="ctrl.task">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.addTask()">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your html to use `$event` like this (ctrl removed because [controllers have been removed from Angular.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/919)):

```dart
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input ng-model="task">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTask($event)">Add</button>
</form>
```

And in your component class:

```dart
void addTask(MouseEvent evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input ng-model="ctrl.task">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.addTask($event)">Add</button>
</form>
```

In the controller:

```dart
$scope.ctrl = function() {
  addTask: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Angular-Dart in the header, not AngularJS